# AAD registration for Dotnet core 3.1 and Angular 9

Tags: c#, angular, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to build a simple spa (angular 9) application with the dotnet core 3.1 on back with Azure Active Directory registration. Is there a documentation or tutorial how to make dotnet core + angular + AAD auth simple application?

I have found the article [AAD with angular, dotnet and MSAL](https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2019/08/adding-azure-active-directory-authentication-connect-angular-app-asp-net-core-web-api-using-msal/), but it seems like is not actual for today.

I registered two app registrations (as it was shown in the article), and took the [client app from the sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/angular9-sample-app) .

My app.module.ts contains:

```
function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<client-id-of-frontend-app-registration>',
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>",
      validateAuthority: true
      // redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
      // postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
      // navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
  };
}
```

After that I created the backend project by:

```
dotnet new webapi --client-id <client-id-of-backend-app-registration> --tenant-id <tenant-id> --domain microsoft.onmicrosoft.com --auth SingleOrg
```

and added angular-app into backend project like it would be with:

```
dotnet new angular
```

so the appsettings.json contains:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ ",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<client-id-of-backend-app-registration>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When I run the project, I click "login" and everything is going OK, and after that all requests through injected HTTPClients contain Bearer tokens.

But when I call any controller marked with [Authorize], it always returns  401.

So maybe some of steps contain mistakes? Or is there a documentation or tutorial how to make dotnet core + angular + AAD auth simple application? At least for another versions of dotnet and angular, but not too old.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should acquire access token in Angular app to access your web api application .

When register the web api application , config the `Expose an API`and `Add a Scope` like : `api://<cliendID>/api-access` ,  and in .net core web application , setting the `ClientId` to `api://<clientid>` .

On Angular application side , you can set `consentScopes` to include your web api's scope :

`consentScopes: [  "api://<clientid>/api-access" ]`

- `consentScopes` : Allows the client to express the desired scopes that should be consented. Scopes can be from multiple resources/endpoints. Passing scope here will only consent it and no access token will be acquired till the time client actually calls the API

And set `protectedResourceMap` to include the api scope to acquire access token :

- `protectedResourceMap` : Mapping of resources to scopes {"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read", "mail.send"]}. Used internally by the MSAL for automatically attaching tokens in webApi calls. This is required only for CORS calls.

For example : `export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=[['https://localhost:44388/api/values', ['api://59b02905-8b6b-4665-a702-321e97392416/api-access']] ];`

You can check the [MSAL For Angular document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) for more details . And [this code sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/angular9-sample-app) is for Angular 9 . You can modify the code sample by updating the configrations in app.module.ts .

**Update :**

You are using Azure AD V2.0 , So the Authority should add `/v2.0` when validating token in web api:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
    options.Authority += "/v2.0";

    // The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new []
    {
     options.Audience,
     $"api://{options.Audience}"
    };


});
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce! please, pay attention that I am using the same angular-9 example (provided in the question body), so these steps are done. For now the www-authenticate header value for this example is earer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/v2.0' is invalid". Seems like it is breaken somewhere in server verification step. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @VVildVVolf ,see updated reply and check whether it helps.

Comment: thank you for the update, according to the error message, it seems like v2.0 is already using.. but i have updated the code accrording to it, and now it says that "The audience '<client-id>' is invalid", do you have any other ideas?

Comment: seems like I need to update options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences array with options.Audience.Replace("api://","")

Comment: That depends which resource you are acquiring , use api://<cliendID>/ or directly resource's client id , but anyway , use jwt.io to decode access token to check what is the audience  , and config by that in your web api .

Comment: In angular if you are using `api://<clientid>/api-access` ,then in web api you should config as `api://<cliendID>`

Answer (score 0):

This is for someone who is looking for complete implementation
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/part-1-integrate-or-authenticate-your-asp-net-web-apis-and-angular-application/